# How to store values that dynamic column generated based on which on table and pass to querystring

Tags: java, jsp

My title might not be clear enough, so let me explain my senario first.
I have a dropdownlist which fetches table list from table.
Now if I choose one of the tables, it will show all the columns by following code:

```
<%          
String columnsql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME as ColumnName FROM information_schema.columns " 
+ "WHERE  table_name = '"+ TableName + "' ORDER  BY ordinal_position";
PrintDebug.println("Table:" + TableName);
ResultSet myRs = aDbManager.retrieveRec(columnsql);

int count =0;
//String[] arraycolumn;
//boolean[] arraycheckbox;
//String[] arraysearch;
while (myRs2.next()) {

    columnname = myRs2.getString("ColumnName");
    //PrintDebug.println("Column"+count+": "  + columnname);        
%>
<label id="lblcolumnname<%=count %>" value=<%=columnname%>> <%=columnname%></label> 
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<input id="chkcheckbox<%=count %>" type="checkbox" value=<%=columnname %>>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<input id="txtsearch<%=count %>" type="text">
<br>
<%
    count++;
}
myRs2.close();
%>
```

So code above will generate every column in the table that I selected. I use javascript to refresh by onchanged.

Question here:
How should I store the columns, irrespective of whether the checkbox is checked or not, and the search textbox in querystring.

sorry for my poor english, confusing to find out the logic i should use on this dynamic generate and store to passing to others page/servlet for processing the querystring for checkbox is checked or not to decide to show the column or not, search textbox is "" or got value to filtering.

was thinking solution by array, is it possible when come to dynamic? because i have to retrieve it on the other side to process the query.
thanks.

Comment: hello anyone can provide some ideas or solutions?

Comment: What you are asking is bit confusing ? If column is checked you want to do some thing when form is submitted. Is that you want ?

Comment: yea, i need to track those is checked for checkbox to bring it to another form with query string, but right now is the way to store and to check whatever the checkbox of each column is checked or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From What I have understood, If column is checked you want to column name and its respective value do some thing when form is submitted.

Add `name` to both check box and text field.

```
<input id="chkColumn<%=count %>" name="columnNames" type="checkbox" value=<%=columnname %>>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<input id="txtSearch<%=count %>" name="val_<%=columnname%>" type="text">
```

Also, Add table name as hidden parameter. So, It will be also submitted

```
<input type="hidden" name="tableName" value="<%=TableName%>" />
```

Now, when your form gets submit in your Servlet / JSP (Not recommended).

You can access all checked check boxes

```
String tableName = request.getParameterValues('tableName');
String[] colNames=request.getParameterValues('columnNames');
```

Process each item in Array and get search value for each column like

```
String strPrefix = "val_";
String strVal = strPrefix + colNames [0]; // you will get value for each column
```

Comment: thanks bro! its did helped me, can i further ask few questions regarding this issue if i still facing problems? quite new to jsp and need someone to show me little ideas/guideline to make it work.

Comment: @user1824745: You are wel-come. You may post new question for new topic. Second, You should create profile and enter details. This will add more values to your profile.

Comment: okie sure, well just found i can create profile cause i using google account to login. :)